# Python code error with sum() function -- syntax works on one platform not another

Tags: python

I'm having an error using Python (inherited code). A Sum() function call that works on one platform is not working on another -- I think it is due to some syntax that is incompatible across platforms. The error I am getting is:

```
bsrlx1(112)% /usr/bin/python run-print.py init data
  File "run-print.py", line 105
    val = sum(1 if x >= 0.5 else 0 for x in metricC[key]);
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Although this syntax works elsewhere. Anyone know of a syntax change or what the issue might be??

The version of Python I am calling is:
Python 2.4.3 (#1, Apr 14 2011, 20:41:59) 
[GCC 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-50)] on linux2

The header file in my program is:

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.5
```

So I think I may be using version 2.5

Comment: `#!/usr/bin/python2.5` is meaningless if you run it explicitly with the python command as in `/usr/bin/python run-print.py init data`

Comment: Not related to your problem but that line should just be `sum(x >= 0.5 for x in metricC[key])` because `bool` is an `int` subclass, so `True` and `False` can be added as if they were `1` and `0`.

Answer (score 8):

You're using a [conditional expression](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions), which was added in Python 2.5.

You're not running `/usr/bin/python2.5`, you're using `/usr/bin/python` (which is 2.4). To run it using the interpreter specified in the file, make it executable and then run it directly:

```
chmod +x run-print.py
./run-print.py
```

It's unlikely that you have Python 2.5 installed though unless your distro has a special backported package for it.

Answer (score 2):

The code is unnecessarily complicated and won't run on Python 2.4, as you have found out. Change it to read:

```
val = sum(1 for x in metricC[key] if x >= 0.5)
```

Benefits: (1) will run on Python 2.4 (2) don't have to explain about adding booleans (3) more efficient (don't waste time adding zeroes) (4) no dopey `;` at the end.